# What methods do i use to implement Android Gestures like "Tap , Double Tap, Hold, Drag , Flick, Swipe " in Touch mode

Tags: android, android-gesture, android-touch-event

I was implementing Different Gestures in Android.
I want to know what methods do I use for implementing different gestures like "Tap,Double Tap,Hold,Drag,Flick,Swipe" etc

Comment: Basically `#setOnTouchListener()` on View...

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Kotlin example that I have implemented

```
private val gestureDetector by lazy {

    GestureDetector(applicationContext, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
            //Your action onLongPress
            super.onLongPress(e)
        }
       // here you can implement other function like onDoubleTap ....
    })
}
```

To use this variable you should use `#setOnTouchListener()` as @ADM suggested

```
your_view.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
            return@setOnTouchListener true
}
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you want this code in Java